# Taylor's series of $f(x) = \ \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{x} \frac{\cos(t)}{t - \frac{\pi}{2}}dt$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Be the function $$f(x) = \
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{x} \frac{\cos(t)}{t - \frac{\pi}{2}}dt.$$ I tried to find the Taylor's series of $f(x)$, but I didn't succeed. What is the Taylor series of $f(x)$? Is there a clever way to find it?

Please let me know if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cos t=\sin(\pi/2-t)$. Change the variable and then integrate the Maclaurin's formula for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: Could you develop your answer?

Comment: There are 3 steps: (1) variable change in the integral, (2) getting Maclaurin for the resulting integrand and (3) integration. When you try going, which step do you get stuck at?

Comment: Why could we integrate an infinite sum? I mean each term of the infinite sum? It is clear we could do it by linearity of a finite sum, but why on an infinite sum?

Comment: @J.Doe Power series can be differentiated and integrated within their radius of convergence (because the convergence is uniform there). Here the radius is infinity (because of $\sin$).